# select rows in group by dataframe before the row which not satisfies a condition (python)

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with some features. I want to group by 'id' feature. Then for each group I want to identify the row which has 'speed' feature value greater than a threshold and select all the rows before this one.

For example, my threshold  is 1.5 for 'speed' feature and my input is:

| id | speed | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 | ... |
| 1 | 1.9 | ... |
| 1 | 1.0 | ... |
| 5 | 0.9 | ... |
| 5 | 1.3 | ... |
| 5 | 3.5 | ... |
| 5 | 0.4 | ... |

And my desired output is:

| id | speed | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 | ... |
| 5 | 0.9 | ... |
| 5 | 1.3 | ... |

Comment: Why you don't have `id = 5 & speed = 3.5` or `id = 1 & speed = 1.9` in your desired output?

Comment: Based on the problem description, speed = 0.9 for id=5 should not be returned in the results. Because the value after this row is 1.3, which is below your threshold. I posted an answer, let me know if it helped.

Comment: because the OP wants all the previous rows before the "value greater than a threshold"

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the desired results:

```
# Create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5],
'speed':[1.2, 1.9, 1.0, 0.9, 1.3, 9.5, 0.4]
})
df
```

output:

```
   id   speed
0   1   1.2
1   1   1.9
2   1   1.0
3   5   0.9
4   5   1.3
5   5   9.5
6   5   0.4
```

---

```
ther = 1.5
s = df.speed.shift(-1).ge(ther)
df[s]
```

Output:

```
   id   speed
0   1   1.2
4   5   1.3
```

Comment: but it this way I lost  the row with id 5and speed 1.3 which should be ok

Comment: I have posted a new answer which is exactly what you need. Check it out and let me know if there was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It took me an hour to figure out but I got what you need. You need to **REVERSE** the dataframe and use `.cumsum()` (cumulative sum) in the groupbyed id's to find the values after the speed threshold you set. Then drop the speeds more than threshold, along with rows that do not satisfy the condition. Finally, reverse back the dataframe:

```
# Create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5],
'speed':[1.2, 1.9, 1.0, 0.9, 1.3, 9.5, 0.4]
})

# Reverse the dataframe
df = df.iloc[::-1]

thre = 1.5
# Find rows with speed more than threshold
df = df.assign(ge=df.speed.ge(thre))

# Groupby and cumsum to get the rows that are after the threshold in with same id
df.insert(0, 'beforethre', df.groupby('id')['ge'].cumsum())


# Drop speed more than threshold  
df['ge'] = df['ge'].replace(True, np.nan)

# Drop rows that don't have any speed more than threshold or after threshold
df['beforethre'] = df['beforethre'].replace(0, np.nan)
df = df.dropna(axis=0).drop(['ge', 'beforethre'], axis=1)

# Reverse back the dataframe 
df = df.iloc[::-1]

# Viola!
df
```

Output:

```
   id   speed
0   1   1.2
3   5   0.9
4   5   1.3
```